# A trigonometric equation i am unable to simplify.

Tags: trigonometry

If $$\frac{\cos x}{\cos y}+\frac{\sin x}{\sin y}=-1$$
Then find the value of $$4\left(\frac{\cos^3 y}{\cos x}+\frac{\sin^3 y}{\sin x}\right)$$

---

I found out that $$\sin(x+y)+\frac{\sin 2y}{2}=0$$
But after this I got no ideas. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) and [format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Please share what you have tried and the context if possible.

Comment: Try to multiply first equation by $\frac{\sin y \cos y}{\sin x \cos x} \sin^2 \left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)$